# including javascript files breaks my background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage I have been working on for a bit here.  I added some pop up web forms I implemented from a "code generator" and then I tried to set a background color when I was finished for my main page.

```
 <style>body {background-color: yellow !important;}</style>
```

For the life of me I couldn't get a background to show until I deleted these three lines of code from the head.  It gets rid of the pop up functionality obviously and displays them as permanent objects on the page but the background finally shows up.  I can't seem to find any info on why this would happen.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

They just seem to be whatever you would call include files in web development (sorry I come from a c background and web development is a bit over my head.)

EDIT:  EVERYONE SUGGESTED PUTTING MY STYLE SCRIPT UNDER THE INCLUDE FILES.
       That is how it was setup.  Sorry for not posting an example.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gauge.css" />
    <link rel=”stylesheet” type="text/css" href="common.css" />

    <style>body {background-color: yellow;}</style>

//PHP STUFF
//JAVASCRIPT STUFF
</head>

<body>
    //TABLES AND BUTTONS FOR POP UP FORMS
</body>
//PHP STUFF
```

EDIT FYI 
body {background-color: yellow !important;}
Does not work.  A yellow bg is seen for 1/4 second then wiped to white.

Comment: The jquery files are to set up a mobile styled environment http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html   ...  If you don't need it, delete it.

Comment: It seems to be required for my pop up forms as I stated.  Plus my target platform is going to be mobile so I need to try to work it out with these files.

Comment: This is a very vague post. I want to know which line # the style tag is placed and which line #s the 3 imports are placed. It could be that the jquery css stylesheet overrides the background color because it was declared in the HTML document *after* you declared the style tag. Just make sure that your style tag is written after all the stylesheet imports because if you set `background-color: yellow` in line 10 and then import a stylesheet in line 11 or higher that possibly sets body's background color to red, the end result will be red.

Comment: By convention the CSS imports go inside the `<head> </head>` tags and the style tags go after the CSS imports but within the head tags. Then the script import statements are place right above the `</body>` tag

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness.  I updated with some code.  I was adding the style script below the includes.

Comment: I pretty much had my code set up that way btrballin.  I have scripts inside head which I will move out now.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yeah I learned from Stackoverflow that when you make the browser load all your js files first, there may be a slight delay to load all the visuals created by the HTML and CSS. So you would want to let the browser load the frontend stuff before it loads the backend.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the yellow background script tag to this `<style>body {background-color: yellow !important;}</style>` like another user suggested?

Comment: I did.  I can now see the yellow background for a second before being wiped.  I have a feeling The pop up windows are doing something.  Looks like I need to go research how they are working a little more maybe.

Answer (score 0):

try to write the CSS style after the 3 lines it might work

Comment: thanks for the response but that is where they were located to begin with.  I even tried <body background="hexVal"> to no avail.

Comment: only the css file effects the style not any of the js files. try to remove just it and leave the two others

Comment: So taking out JUST that stylesheet line worked.....but it broke my pop up form functionality.  Sets them as permanent objects on the page.  Thanks for trying again :)

Comment: then open the link and copy the whole code and paste it in local file and use it , then try to search for body{ background-color:#XXXXX } or something similar in it and delete it. last try i hope ^_^

Comment: I was wondering about doing that.  I dont even like the fact I need internet connection for that to work.  My website is less of a website and more of a local (inside own home) web interface for micro controller stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">` links to a stylesheet.  Odds are good that it's overwriting what you're putting in.  Put in your code after your link to that style sheet, and it *should* work.  It still may not, however.  It depends on the styling.

Comment: If you meant put the background code after the link to the stylesheet that is where it is located.  I usually put most of everything after links to those types of files.

Comment: Then the stylesheet is overriding the style you want to use.  This generally happens due to specificity.  You could try utilizing `!important`.

Comment: hmmm.  thanks for the tip!  I will go research that.